# Understand Compile-Time Assertions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

http://erdani.com/index.php/books/modern-c-design/errata/
Page 25:

```
template<bool> struct CompileTimeChecker
{
        CompileTimeChecker(...);
};
template<> struct CompileTimeChecker<false> {};
#define STATIC_CHECK(expr, msg) \
    { \
        CompileTimeError<expr> \
        ERROR_##msg; \
        (void)ERROR_##msg; }

template<class To, class From>
To safe_reinterpret_cast( From from )
{
        STATIC_CHECK( sizeof( From ) <= sizeof(To ),
                      Destination_Type_Too_Narrow );
        return reinterpret_cast<To>(from);
}

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //STATIC_CHECK( true,
    //              Destination_Type_Too_Narrow );

    double d = 1.0;
    int* i = safe_reinterpret_cast<int*>( &d );

    return 0;
}
```

Question 1> Why the compiler complains the usage of `Destination_Type_Too_Narrow` ?

> Error 4   error C2065: 'ERROR_Destination_Type_Too_Narrow' : undeclared
>   identifier

Question 2> Why should we always use the cast of `(void)` in the macro?
To avoid seeing the unused variable warning?

Question 3> Why STATIC_CHECK( false, XXX ) will cause compile error?

Thank you

Comment: I do hope you know about [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static_assert)?

Comment: VS2013 supports [`static_assert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293588.aspx), is there a reason why you are not using it?  `static_assert(sizeof(To) >= sizeof(From), "Destination Type Too Narrow");`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, need to understand the concept and theory

Comment: @q0987: `static_assert` takes two parameters - a compile-time expression and a string literal. If the expression evaluates to false, the compile fails and the string literal is displayed in the compiler output.  The logic is handled by the compiler itself, not your code.

Answer (score 0):

1: You aren't trying to use template function, so compiler doesn't compile any of the template realization, so assert doesn't go off. Basically, compiler doesn't emit any code for the templates that you don't use (and this feature is used throughout template libraries like `boost` for different purposes).

2: Casting to `void` is a common method to avoid unused variable warning. If assert didn't fail in your example, then you would have an unused variable in your code, and bringing up warning that you can avoid is considered bad tone.